# Xcode is not showing the NSLogs from iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

I have put up with this glitch for a while now, I just accepted that the NSLogs stopped working on my devices, and if I really needed to log something, then I would just use a simulator and it worked just fine. I know what buttons to click and whatever to show the log, I have "All output" selected, so I know that is not the problem.

How do I re-enable NSLogs?

I'm thinking that I somehow disabled it from my device all together, or some certificate isn't right so it's not showing the logs. Either way I'm definitely frustrated, I NEED to use the logs now, and I really need help!

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Xcode 6 : open Xcode --> Window --> Devices select the device that you have connected at the bottom of window you will find all logs

[image]

if you are using Xcode less than 6 (for ex Xcode 5): open Xcode --> Window --> Organizer --> Devices

[image]